# Why is my array coming out like this?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am querying the DB successfully using an array and I am getting the correct result. But I am having difficulty using the results because of the way the array is created.

Here is the OUTPUT:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 1@1.1
        )
        [1] => 2@2.2
    )
    [2] => 3@3.3
)
```

Here is how the code is generated:

```
$owners_string = $row['profile_id'];
$owners_stringd = unserialize($owners_string);
foreach ($owners_stringd as $profileid => $valuee) {
    if ($valuee) {
        $sql = "select email from {$mysql_tbl_pre}profile where profile_id = '$valuee' ";
        $err = mysqli_query($estate_db, $sql);
        if (!$err) 
            error_dlg(mysqli_error($estate_db));
        elseif (mysqli_num_rows($err) <= 0) 
            info_dlg("Error");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($err)) 
            $new_array[$profileid] = $row['email'];

        $new_array = array($new_array);
        foreach ($new_array as $emailvalue)
            $emailsd = print_r($emailvalue, true);

    } else {
        $emailsd = "";
    }
}
```

I know how to implode the results, but when i do implode this result, is comes out as "Array, 1@1.1" (which ever email was last).

I need it to be one entire result such as 1@1.1,2@2.2,3@3.3

These are two separate Tables. The first Tables stores a string of Ids that, the second Tables has each Id in its own row with an email in a separate column.

Solution from the while loop:

```
while ($thisemail = mysqli_fetch_array($rsz)) {
    $emailsd .= $thisemail['email'] . ',';
}
foreach ($emailsd as $emailvalue)
$email = print_r($emailvalue, true);
```

Comment: It would be really nice if you **show** us how you build this array

Comment: Share the code you use to fetch the query results

Comment: Can you please explain what output you really want?

Comment: show the code of mysql query and how u fetched it

Comment: do you know what does print_r do?

Comment: You keep assigning $new_array to a new array, so instead of getting 1 array with 3 keys, you're getting an array within an array within an array. Remove `$new_array = array($new_array);`

Comment: For starters `$owners_string = unserialize($row['profile_id']);` Why not just write it in a single line?

Comment: when I remove the `$new_array = array($new_array);`, then it only shows the last email, and not all of them that was fetched for the result.
Thank you for the quick method to unserialize from the start, I didnt know that.

Comment: Change `$new_array[$profileid] = $row['email'];` to `$new_array[$profileid][] = $row['email'];`

Comment: Please get into the habit of using `{}` on If's and While's etc etc even if they are single instruction blocks. Makes the code much easier to read and follow **and debug**

Comment: @RiggsFolly, changing to your suggestions resulted in
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => ) ) 
`

Comment: Someone posted a piece of code which I used. The code is now removed, but within that piece I found the solution! Thank you very much for the assistance.